# Is it possible to generate a lib through the code of a dll?

Tags: c++, dll, lib

I have a C ++ project that when compiled turns into a dll. Is it possible for me to compile the same code and generate a static lib?

If possible, would I have to change a lot of the code structure?

Comment: What, for you, is the difference between a dll and a lib?

Comment: What is a "font" in this context?

Comment: How exactly do you built into a dll? Do you have a makefile? A project configuration? A commandline?

Comment: When I speak source, I mean the code. The c ++ dll is being compiled in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Um, was that meant to answer any of my comments?

Comment: I don't find a guide for that old Visual Studio version but [here's one for VS2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=vs-2015) - What does `wininet` and `delphi` have to do with anything in this question?

Comment: Currently it is unclear what you mean with the terms `font` and `lib` and what the actual problem is. Also you did tag `delphi` but never mention it anywhere in your question.
Please provide more information on what problem you are trying to solve and please be as specific as possible.

Comment: I don't see what is unclear about this question !

Comment: @engf-010 "lib" is not necessarily a term I would directly associate with a static library but as an abbreviation to "library" in general, contrary to "dll" that refers to a shared library. So the first part of the question is not phrased exactly - but that's nitpicking. The real issue comes from the fact that OP wrote `font` where it should read `code` and that the question was tagged with `delphi` and `wininet`. I suggest you check the edit history.

Comment: @simon kramer: don't need to see  the edit-history ,followed this question from the start. True, the (original) text was mostly irrelevant ,but the questions are very clear and simple (as is the answer) even if of low quality.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to generate a lib through the code of a dll?
Yes.

Would I have to change a lot of the code structure?
If done right : not really.

Your dll-header(s) probably makes the distiction for importing and exporting declarations/definitions.
You need to make a third distinction for non-dll usage (no importing exporting).

The biggest change would probably involve separating your projects structure.